# Laravel facade and tight coupled controllers

Tags: laravel, facade, tightly-coupled-code

I have a hard time to understand how I can do this best. I understand how the facade works as syntactic sugar to present a clear static code layout style while keeping the code loose-coupled and testable.

However I have the following problem. Whenever I have a controller the controller is dependent on loads of classes. Lets take the input class as an example. 
Every controller is an IoC container so actually this is good. Because if I would like to change the input class with another class. I just have to create a new class which implement the right interface. However this means that EVERY controller in my app is dependent on the same input class. Do I understand this right?

So I read this very nice article: http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/16/using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-in-laravel-4-controllers

In short it suggests to use dependency injection (DI) in your controllers. E.G.

```
class UsersController extends BaseController
{
    protected $response;
    protected $request;
    protected $validator;
    protected $hasher;
    protected $user;
    public function __construct(
        Response $response,
        \Illuminate\Http\Request $request,
        \Illuminate\Validation\Factory $validator,
        \Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher $hasher,
        User $user
    ) {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return $this->response->make('Hello World!');
    }
}
```

and

```
$app->bind('UsersController', function($app) {
    $controller = new UsersController(
        new Response,
        $app->make('request'),
        $app->make('validator'),
        $app->make('hash'),
        new User
    );
    return $controller;
});
```

This does make sense but it was not the philosophy of the framework because it bypasses the facade... I would like to hear opinions about this approach. Is this good practice or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've been following the same tutorial as another guy whose question I just answered. Instead of repeating myself, please see [my answer to his question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848849/280329).